# Export-SPWeb permissions

Tags: powershell

When using Export-SPWeb to export a site does it copy permissions with it? When the export is running can it still be used by others? Once the export is complete will it be usable as before?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can continue to use the site while executing Export-SPWeb. And, if you want to include the user security settings in the site use the IncludeUserSecurity parameter